# Templated function as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have code that looks like

```
template<typename C>
void invoke() {
  if (thing_known_at_runtime) {
    C::template run<int>(4);
  } else {
    C::template run<char>('a');
  }
}

struct output {
  template<typename T>
  static void run(T x) {
    cout << x;
  }
};

invoke<output>();
```

And it works.

But I don't like the heavyweight definition of output.  I'd like to be able to write:

```
template<typename T>
void output(T x) {
  cout << x;
}
```

And then call either invoke<output>() or invoke(output).  Is there a way to define invoke so that this works?

(Both output and invoke are more complicated -- this is a simplified version for asking the question with.  No, solutions that involve knowing int when I call invoke are not helpful.)

Comment: Is C++11 allowed? And am I understanding correctly that you just want to call a function with stored arguments?

Comment: How can std::function help me?  Yes, C++11 is allowed.  I want to call a function with stored (actually calculated) arguments *and template parameters*.  In fact, let me edit the example to make that clear.

Comment: Are you not willing to define two versions of `invoke()`?

Comment: That won't work smoothly, as functions can only be passed via a function pointer, which needs a concrete type at the point of passing (i.e., you can't supply the template parameter later on).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such thing. You should knowns, what you want to do, BEFORE call to `invoke`. Something like this will work well

```
void invoke(const std::function<void()>& func)
{
   func();
}

template<typename T>
void output (const T& val)
{
   std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

if (rand() % 2)
{
   invoke(std::bind<void(&)(const int&)>(&output, globals::value_calculated));
}
else
{
   invoke(std::bind<void(&)(const char&)>(&output, globals::value));
}
```

Full example on lws: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uLIr4$0